# Nginx protect directory with password, except for specific ip's

Tags: nginx, password-protected

In my Nginx setup I would like to password protect some website, except when I access it from my ip at home. How do I set this up?

Also, except for getting access to my home pc, is this safe?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

After long searching I found it myself.

When satisfy_any is put on ["Directive solves access with at least one successful checking, executed by modules HttpAccessModule or HttpAuthBasicModule"](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpCoreModule#satisfy_any)

```
  location / {
    satisfy any;
    allow  10.1.1.10;
    deny   all;
    auth_basic            "closed site";
    auth_basic_user_file  /data/www_data/htpasswd;
  }
```

(`satisfy any` is the new syntax, `satisfy_any` threw a warning. The documentation I can't find however)